# Array of different objects

Tags: c++, arrays

Alright so what I am trying to do is basically this.

I have an Account class, then I have a CheckingAccount and SavingsAccount class that inherit from the Account class.

In my program I have an array called accounts. It is going to hold objects of both types of accounts.

```
Account** accounts;
accounts = new Account*[numAccounts];


accountFile >> tempAccountNum >> tempBalance >> tempTransFee;
CheckingAccount tempAccount(tempBalance, tempAccountNum, tempTransFee);
accounts[i] = tempAccount;
```

I get an error when trying to assign tempAccount to the accounts array.

No suitable conversion function from "CheckingAccount" to "Account" exists.

How do I make the accounts array hold both kinds of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element in `accounts` is an `Account*`. That is, a "pointer to `Account`". You're trying to assign an `Account` directly. Instead, you should be taking the address of that account:

```
accounts[i] = &tempAccount;
```

Remember that this pointer will be pointing at an invalid object once `tempAccount` has gone out of scope.

Consider avoiding arrays and pointers. Unless you have a good reason not to, I would use a `std::vector` of `Account`s (not `Account*`s):

```
std::vector<Account> accounts;

accountFile >> tempAccountNum >> tempBalance >> tempTransFee;
accounts.emplace_back(tempBalance, tempAccountNum, tempTransFee);
```

Comment: ok, so now I am at the problem you said I would end up at. Where as soon as I close my accounts file. The accounts array becomes NULL. How would I be able to keep these objects in the array after closing the file?

Comment: @user2234688 You should post a new question. I'm not avoiding it- that's just generally how things are done here!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to assign the address of tempAccount into the accounts array.

accounts[i] = &tempAccount;

Because, when dealing with polymorphism in C++, you use the address of the object rather than the object itself.